# get remote Ip address or machine name

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, ip-address

I have my GUI files published on a server... this server is where the IIS is running..

Now i access my GUI from a remote machine. how can i get this machines IP address or username.

I get the server name of the machine using this code:

```
string svrName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
```

please help thanks...

maybe i was not clear enough:

> Let me explain again..

there are 2 machines A and B.. A is where i have my published files for the GUI and also the IIS... the above code gives me the name of machine A

now i call the GUI from machine B. and i want the name of machine B

Comment: What do you mean by "this machine"? You have two machines. Which machine's IP address do you want and on which machine is the code running?

Comment: What do you mean by "access". Is it TCP between the two applications or are you using remote desktop or what? What is the protocol of access?

Comment: the code is running on the server machine... but my gui is running on my machine... i want the address of my machine...

Comment: access = running the GUI

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get a remote user's IP from Asp.Net, you can use `Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]` or `Request.UserHostAddress`.

The `Request` object should be available anywhere in your ASPX page.

I don't think it's possible to reliably get the hostname through ServerVariables.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming I understand what you're asking, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request will give your server-side code [lots of information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest_members%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) about the client making the request.